# Console App wont stay open, after setting isBackground = true on thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console-application

so I have created a server which needs to listen for clients to connect and in the constructor of my server class I have:

```
class Server
{
    private Thread listenerThread;
    private TcpListener listener;

    public Server()
    {
        this.listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
        listenerThread = new Thread(ListenMethod) { IsBackground = true };

        listenerThread.Start();
    }


    private void ListenMethod()
    {
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I created the instance of server in my main like so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Server s = new Server();
    }
}
```

The server should stay open cause of the ListenMethod running and the while loop, yet the program seems to complete the constructor and closes the program.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why not just make the main thread the server? Seems kind of pointless to create a background thread when the main thread is doing nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Background threads will not keep a console application alive, as is their purpose.  The Server class instance is also going out of scope because it isn't used by anything; in a Release build of this application it might not even be compiled into the application and optimised away.  You need to do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Server server = new Server();

    Console.Write("The server is running. Press any key to stop the server.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    server.Stop();
}
```

Comment: You also have `listener` not being initialised, as noted in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are instantiating your `listner` instance, before you call `Start()`, so the code is probably crashing on `listener.Start()` due to a `NullReferenceException`

I would expect something like this:

```
 private void ListenMethod()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener();
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I missed this out when I was creating the question. I do indeed initialise. I have changed the op to reflect this :)